# C++ strange value during calculation

Tags: c++, math

I have the following line:

```
int iEndFrame = ((uByteStart + uByteCount-1) / g_iByteSize1FrameDecoded) + 1;
```

My values are:

```
uByteStart = 2147479808
uByteCount = 8684
g_iByteSize1FrameDecoded = 1920
```

However, iEndFrame becomes -1118477, and that can not be correct.

Does anybody see my error?

Thank you for the help!

ps: 
The declaration is:

```
void CApp::pCalcFrames(int uByteStart, int uByteCount, int &uStartFrame, int &uFramesToRead, int& uOffset)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like pointed in other answers, you have an integer overflow.

It should be easily resolved in your case (assuming the final result can fit into `int`):

Instead of:

```
int iEndFrame = ((uByteStart + uByteCount-1) / g_iByteSize1FrameDecoded) + 1;
```

do:

```
int iEndFrame = uByteStart / g_iByteSize1FrameDecoded + 
                uByteCount / g_iByteSize1FrameDecoded - 1 / g_iByteSize1FrameDecoded + 1;
```

Note the rounding though.

Comment: Okay, I need change the variable from int to a "larger" type. What should I choose instead?

Comment: And is there a way to throw an error? I need to change a lot of variables to hold bigger values, and I am afraid that I will miss some if no errors are thrown.

Comment: If you don't want to apply the method that I suggested, you can change the types to `unsigned` since they are obviously non-negative. If that's not enough, `long long` might help

Answer (score 2):

`uByteStart  + uByteCount` is wrapping around to negative since it's exceeding the size of an `int` on your platform (assume 32 bit).

It's important not to do this as, technically, the behaviour is undefined so your code will not be portable:

> (§5/5 C++03, §5/4 C++11) If during the evaluation of an expression,
>   the result is not mathematically defined or not in the range of
>   representable values for its type, the behavior is undefined.

One solution (but note it will not be as precise due to the truncation effects of successive integer divisions) would be to write

```
uByteStart / g_iByteSize1FrameDecoded + (uByteCount-1) / g_iByteSize1FrameDecoded + 1;
```

which reduces the size of the summation arguments.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like an overflow. An `int` can't hold values larger than `INT_MAX`.

Answer (score 1):

Your `int`s are probably 32-bit wide. If so, your arithmetic calculations produce signed integer overflow, which triggers *undefined behavior*.